# Wrong csv format when exporting sql query result

Tags: mysql, sql

[CSV Format ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Au7p.png)In table1, there are three columns: COMPANY, AMOUNT and Vendor.
And after the query, we will get a table with 6 columns: VENDOR, A, B, C, D, Total.

```
SELECT 'VENDOR','A','B','C','D','Total'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    VENDOR,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'A' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'B' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS B,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'C' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS C,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'D' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS D,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS Grand_Total
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/result.csv'
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME;
```

The problem is: when I tried to export the query result into a new csv file result, I found the content in csv file really messy...
And in my result.csv: the first line is VENDORABCDTotal and the second line is Mike12340001234. All fields and data are in the first column in csv file.

Comment: Please explain “really messy”

Comment: In my csv file, all fields are in the same cell...

Comment: For the select before the union, where is your FROM clause?

Comment: Edit your post and add the first few lines of the output file.

Comment: For the first SELECT, it just includes the header of the original table in SQL.

Comment: And in my result.csv: the first line is VENDORABCDTotal and the second line is Mike12340001234. All fields and data are in the first column in csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to terminated each field by comma and each row by a new line character : 
Please export data using below command:

```
SELECT 'VENDOR','A','B','C','D','Total'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    VENDOR,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'A' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'B' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS B,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'C' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS C,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN COMPANY = 'D' THEN AMOUNT
        ELSE ''
    END) AS D,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS Grand_Total
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME;
```

Check this !

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the vendor name and the amount under columns A,B,C,D are not in the same line. Besides, the amount is in the wrong format... For example, it shows: 1.00E+05 ... I'm quite confused

Comment: Share  your data. Its difficult to understand what data this table contain.

Comment: @TaohaoWang: I have updated the answer. execute and check.

Comment: I tried it but there was an error: Field separator argument is not what is expected. I have posted my screenshot of csv file.

Comment: the data which is showing in E+ format is the properties of Microsoft Excel. use right click to Format cell of your excel and you can convert is as an integer.

Comment: Btw, do you know how to put vendor name and the amount in the same line?